# "Should I" or "Shall I" or …?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Should” vs. “Shall” vs. “Will” vs. “Must”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/should-vs-shall-vs-will-vs-must)

> Shall I upload the pictures?

I'm not sure how to start this sentence. If I offer someone to do something (like uploading pictures as in the example above, or closing the door), how do I say this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Should" vs. "Shall" vs. "Will" vs. "Must"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/should-vs-shall-vs-will-vs-must)

Comment: Also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3/2303 has a pertinent explanation as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be understood either way.   It may sound a bit quaint to use "shall," but it will certainly be understood.  Though it's used less often in American English, it is probably at least as clear when used in an interrogative sentence such as the one you're asking about.

Even more clear would be to ask, "Would you like me to upload the pictures?".
Alternately, "You'd like me to upload the pictures now?" or a different phrase referring to a time frame.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct, should is more polite, shall is probably, less used