# What is the best word for this context: May or Should?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

•   This Quotation is a confidential document provided strictly for the party to whom it is addressed and **may** neither be used for any purpose other than as intended nor shared with any other party

•   This Quotation is a confidential document provided strictly for the party to whom it is addressed and **should** neither be used for any purpose other than as intended nor shared with any other party

Comment: Related question, [Does 'should' imply an unquestionable command?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/does-should-imply-an-unquestionable-command). The link might be helpful to you. As a legal term, **may not** is very strong. If you Google legal documents, you will see it is very broadly used. **May not** in the legal context means "you are absolutely not allowed to do it under any circumstances and if you do it, you will be sued."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the text in question is a disclaimer, which is 'legalese' and should be written or approved by lawyers, not via random internet consultation.

Answer (score 2):

*May* is the appropriate word here. It is a specific denial of permission, saying what people are not allowed to do.

If you use *should*, then you are advising against doing something, implying that people are allowed to do it but it is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

The rest of your sentence needs some work too, but the word you're looking for is ***must***.