# When to use 'will' and when to use 'shall'?

Tags: confusables

I always get confused in using will and shall.

Same way when to use **must** and **should**.

Comment: Wow, you asked a question where the title was entirely in caps on an English Language & Usage site! I'll tidy this up a bit.

Comment: For your second question, please see [When must one use “should” and when should one use “must”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/when-must-one-use-should-and-when-should-one-use-must).

Answer (score 0):

"Will" and "Shall" are very nearly synonyms, and I can't think of any place where one can be used but not the other.  Also, this question seems to have been answered already [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will).

But "Must" and "Should" are entirely different (and you should probably ask a separate question for these two words).  The short answer though is that "Must" is definitive, and "Should" is not.  "Should" indicates a likelihood that an activity is something that one needs to do, while "Must" is an activity where there is no option to do it or not (and thus, using it to say someone *should* do something would be a hyperbole)

Comment: "Shall we go?" is different from "Will we go?", for example.

Comment: @tchrist True, I hadn't thought of that one. Still, the question seems to have already been answered elsewhere in any case.